# How to make My Website project Responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

So I have been tasked to design a website as my project. I have created my project but when I resize my browser all the text and photos starts overlapping. I have tried everything but it still happens.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
}

.controller {
  background: #357EC7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

.container .main-nav {
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .main-nav a {
  margin: 30px;
}

.container .main-nav i {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  color: black;
}

.container .main-nav i:hover {
  color: #357EC7;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container .content {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .content #album {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background: rgb(95, 95, 95);
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
}

.container .content #album #album-image {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container .content #album #album-image img {
  width: 65%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon #al-head {
  height: 30%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon #al-text {
  height: 45%;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon #al-icon {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon #al-icon a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .content #album #album-text-icon #al-icon a:hover {
  color: hsl(210, 80%, 70%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container .content #music {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .content #music .song-info {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container .content #music .song-info:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.container .content #music .song-info p:nth-of-type(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

.container .content #music .song-info p {
  flex: 6;
  text-align: justify;
}

.container .content #music .song-info div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 6;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .content #music .song-info div a {
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container .content #music .song-info div a:hover {
  background: #357EC7;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.controller {
  display: flex;
}

.controller #control-image {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controller #control-image img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.controller #control-text {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.controller #control-icon {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  gap: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.controller #control-icon i {
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.controller #control-icon i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://i.postimg.cc/W1DVg7pV/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Music</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-soundcloud"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-spotify"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
      <section id="album">
        <div id="album-image">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bwKhT2dt/music-cover.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="album-text-icon">
          <div id="al-head">
            <h1>Empires On Fire</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="al-text">
            <p>BANNERS</p>
            <p>2017 . Album . 5songs</p>
          </div>
          <div id="al-icon">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i> Play all</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Add to</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i> More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="music">
        <div class="song-info">
          <p>1.</p>
          <p>Someone To You</p>
          <p>BANNERS</p>
          <p>3:39</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Cloud Sync</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="song-info">
          <p>2.</p>
          <p>Empires On Fire</p>
          <p>BANNERS</p>
          <p>3:39</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Cloud Sync</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="song-info">
          <p>3.</p>
          <p>Firefly</p>
          <p>BANNERS</p>
          <p>3:29</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Cloud Sync</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="song-info">
          <p>4.</p>
          <p>Into The Storm</p>
          <p>BANNERS</p>
          <p>3:40</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Cloud Sync</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="song-info">
          <p>5.</p>
          <p>Holy Ground</p>
          <p>BANNERS</p>
          <p>4:18</p>
          <div>
            <a href="#">Cloud Sync</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
  <div class="controller">
    <div id="control-image">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/bwKhT2dt/music-cover.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="control-text">
      <p>Someone To You</p>
      <p>BANNERS</p>
    </div>
    <div id="control-icon">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward-step"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-pause"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-rotate-right"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-shuffle"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


```
````

I have tried changing the padding and height but my page is still not responsive. If any one can please help me making this page responsive this will be very helpful.

Comment: Try using sensitive design. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) is the world's most popular frontend framework (a set of CSS classes and some JS scripts). It offers classes like `hidden-lg` (this hides an element on "large" screens — which screens are large is described in their docs).

Comment: It's a very broad question, you will have to learn about flexboxes and media queries

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions for your current scenario. The first one would be to employ bootstrap. This can be done by adding to your head tag the following links:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- Bootstrap Links -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Following this, you can use throughout your divs and HTML tags classes the grid classes included in the bootstrap documents. Here is a link where the grid system is described:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Your screen is virtually divided into 12 units, and depending on the screen sizes being `lg`, `md`, or `sm` you can assign certain tags to occupy a certain amount of units based on your preferences. For instance, if you assign a `div` the class `col-lg-4`, it will occupy 4 units (4/12 = 1/3 of the screen) on large screens, and for medium and small screens you can change this by assigning `col-md-6` or `col-sm-12`. These are just examples, you will decide how your project looks on the different screen sizes and devices. Virtually, using these bootstrap classes will provide your project with the desired responsiveness.

The other solution is to employ flexbox and CSS media queries and manually code all the necessary lines of CSS to make your project responsive. Here is a link that goes over the CSS media queries:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

I will also include a basic template for the media queries that you can use, although if you want your website to be fully responsive you will require more queries

```
/* Mobile Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {}

/* Tablet Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {}

/* Desktop Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {}
```

Once you implement these, you will have to play around with the code until it looks how you desire it to look. Here is a link going over flexbox as well:

https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/

Hope this helps!